# Where are the objects stored in web application?

Tags: scala, memory, playframework

So I mean (I'm talking about web application based on Play Framework, but the question is about web applications generally), if I have a **class Person**,

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

and **List[Person]**. View look something like this:
[image: View]

So, you enter name and age, push "Add" button, and new **object Person** is added to the **List[Person]**, that goes to the view. Now the question, where **List[Person]** should be stored? Because if a lot of people are using this web app in the same moment, the server memory would be overflowed if **List[Person]** instanes are stored there.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) is used for solving this problem.

So here what you can do is the webservice saves the data inside the database and can fetch the data from it.

If you want the data to be fetched pretty fast you can increase the cache size of your play framework and store the data there. But it totally depends upon your use case how much data you are storing 
There is also the concept of [in-memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database) database, for fast fetching.

I hope I solved your problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So the table in database should have columns ID, NAME, AGE (and name of user who created this object?).  I missunderstand how to fetch specific user's data from database. Are there some good examples/patterns?